# My woocommerce checkout page and woocommerce setting page are not responding

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My woocommerce checkout page and woocommerce setting page are not responding quickly. They take ages to load and bring down the whole site. I tried disabling all the plugins and seems to the problem with woocommerce. I also tried reinstalling the woocommerce plugin in case there was anything wrong with the previous plugin. This problem seems to happen after I updated the woocommerce database as shown in the notification "WooCommerce Database update required". 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone to 'WooCommerce' => 'Status' and reviewed the results?